# Auto-adapt for div container in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a div that varies in size. It can have dimensions:
height: 780 and width: 1390, or height: 524 and width: 930.

The React application displays on two types of screens:
FullHD 1920x1080 and 4K 3840x2054.

I would like the div to vary in size and to vary in screen, to always maintain the same proportion in the screen and the same dimensions in both types of screen.

For example I want the div to vary also on other types of screens such as those of a tablet, a smartphone or for example 1920x1200 screens. I want to make it as flexible as possible.

In the case of 4K the div looks much smaller than the rest of the screen, while in fullHD it takes up most of the screen.

I tried using vh and vw in the following way:

```
 function convertPxToVH(px) {
    var vh = (px / 1080) * 100;
    return vh;
  }

  function convertPxToVW(px) {
    var vw = (px / 1920) * 100;
    return vw;
  }
```

In this way I would obtain the same vh and vw for each type of screen. But doesn't work well beacuse in 4k screen the div have more space around respect t fullHD.

This is the result I would like to obtain (obviously I would like it to fit with other types of screens as well).
Thanks in advance to whoever will help me[image]

Comment: What's your reasoning between wanting to do it in Javascript instead of with CSS media queries?

Comment: because I want the div to also vary on other types of screens such as those of a tablet, a smartphone or for example 1920x1200 screens. I want to make it as flexible as possible. with media queries can i make it so flexible? @AmyBlankenship

Comment: You can do that with css, yes including varying sizes on different screens and consistent proportions, there is no need to use javascript.

Comment: How I can do that? @MaximilianBallard

Comment: One way is to use media queries for your specific sizes. You can also use the new CSS aspect-ratio property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio. I'd use it with aspect-ratio and a clamped width https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/aspect-ratio/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with css using `width` and `height` and `vw` and `vh`.

`vw` represents percent of width of viewport so `80vw` is 80 percent of the width. This is the same with `vh`, only with height.

```css
body { background-color: #00305e; }

.keep-prop {
  background-color: #ffc700;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>
  
  <body>

    <div class="keep-prop">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```